# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null with px.line

Tags: pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe with 10 columns and a datetime index of 6 days with hourly frequency. When I try to do a simple px.line(df) I get the following error:

```
'''df
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
DATETIME                                        
2022-03-15 01:00:00 21.26   20.51   21.22   20.51   20.90   21.04   22.60   21.41   21.30   20.34
2022-03-15 02:00:00 17.17   16.66   17.80   16.60   17.59   17.64   18.75   17.49   17.72   16.50
2022-03-15 03:00:00 14.99   14.52   15.49   14.36   15.29   15.42   16.54   15.16   15.50   14.23
2022-03-15 04:00:00 15.05   14.63   15.81   14.51   15.64   15.70   16.69   15.35   15.73   14.42
2022-03-15 05:00:00 16.39   15.95   17.24   15.88   17.06   17.07   18.06   16.80   17.10   15.81
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2022-03-20 20:00:00 28.54   27.21   29.29   28.36   28.64   28.11   29.95   28.60   28.43   28.49
2022-03-20 21:00:00 28.00   26.65   28.25   27.64   27.60   27.24   29.24   27.87   27.62   27.68
2022-03-20 22:00:00 18.78   17.58   18.13   18.10   17.49   17.58   19.76   17.86   18.00   17.91
2022-03-20 23:00:00 13.00   11.87   11.85   12.15   11.19   11.53   13.83   11.55   11.98   11.84
2022-03-21 00:00:00 9.34    8.25    8.09    8.49    7.43    7.82    10.11   7.61    8.25    8.15

px.line(df)

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
stack trace

Error generating stack: s is not a function
TypeError: s is not a function
    at Function.prepareStackTraceWithRawStackAssignment....

'''
```

Comment: Specifying only a data frame does not draw a graph. Please refer to the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/). Data format is vertical format.

Comment: You should look here for some examples: https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for same structure dataframe that you describe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.date_range("15-Mar-2022", "21-Mar-2022", freq="1H"),
    data=np.random.uniform(8, 22, [145, 10]),
)

px.line(df)
```